# alpine causes error while installing python package

Tags: python, docker, pypi

While developing docker image there is a python requirement which is `google-crc32c>=1.0.0,<1.1.2` and I'm running on alpine linux

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine
RUN python -m venv /py && \
    /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
    apk add --update --no-cache postgresql-client && \
    apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp-deps \
        build-base postgresql-dev musl-dev linux-headers && \
    /py/bin/pip3 install -r /requirements.txt && \
    (Some commands here)
```

`requirements.txt`

```
google-crc32c>=1.0.0,<1.1.2
```

So, while the image is building and It installs the requirements file and this error hits

```
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/33/cf/458dc6e18674d9a84f8dab0acf7de8945b9aca379f809fcc2b2aa03973b6/google-crc32c-1.0.0.tar.gz#sha256=9439b960b6ecd847557675d130fc3626d762bf535da595c20a6949a705fb3eae (from https://pypi.org/simple/google-crc32c/) (requires-python:>=3.5). Command errored out with exit status 1: /py/bin/python /tmp/pip-standalone-pip-e64df5j1/__env_pip__.zip/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-ya19g92u/normal --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'cffi>=1.0.0' Check the logs for full command output.
#10 180.7 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement google-crc32c<1.1.2,>=1.0.0 (from versions: 0.0.1, 0.0.2, 0.1.0, 1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2)
#10 180.7 ERROR: No matching distribution found for google-crc32c<1.1.2,>=1.0.0
```

Even I have given only the available versions from pypi. Please help me resolve this error.

Comment: The min & max versions are reversed in the error, for what it's worth. Hard to tell without actually seeing any Dockerfile / requirements.txt though

Comment: @SiHa files added!

Comment: Have you tried in your local machine the same requirements.txt to see if raises an error?

Comment: @Max it's fine with ubuntu but causes error in alpine

Comment: @SiHa Could you help me with this please

Comment: Not really, because you've not provided your Dockerfile (or at least enough of it to replicate). Where does the requirements.txt get added?